# display confirm message before delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2-jquery

i'm trying to display a confirm message before delete, I'm using jqgrid

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="eleveId"
                    title="Supprimer" 
                    editable="false" 
                    sortable="false"
                    align="center"
                    formatter="formatImage"
                    onclick="$.publish('edit_eleve');"

    />
```

and i'm formatting this column with an image

```
function formatImage(cellvalue, options, row) {
    return "<img src='"+ context_path +"/images/page_edit.png' onClick='$.publish("+"&apos;edit_eleve&apos;, {old_name:" +"&apos;"+cellvalue+"&apos;"+ "})' />";
}
```

the delete is working fine,but i have to refresh the page to see changes.

my question now is how to display a confirm message before delete.

here is the rest of code :

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
    $.subscribe('edit_eleve', function(event, data) { 

            editEleve(data.old_name);


        return false;

    });
}); 


function editEleve(old_name) {
    AUI().use('liferay-portlet-url', 'aui-dialog', 'aui-io', 'event', 'event-custom', function(A) {
        //alert("=============="+A);
        var editEleveAction = Liferay.PortletURL.createActionURL();
        editEleveAction.setWindowState("exclusive");
        editEleveAction.setPortletId("Injazalmaghrib_WAR_Injazalmaghribportlet");

        editEleveAction.setParameter("struts.portlet.action","/eleve/editeleve");
        editEleveAction.setParameter("oldName", old_name);
        //alert("=============="+editBookmarkAction);
        var dialog = new A.Dialog({ 

        }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {
                    uri: editEleveAction.toString()
                });

        //dialog.show();

     });
}
```

any one can help please :).

PS: i did it in javascript but i have the famous problem of :
"Prevent this page from creating additional dialog boxes"
"Empecher cette page de générer des boites de dialogue supplémentaire"

Comment: Any time you do an alert confirm or prompt more than twice, browsers will offer that option, there's nothing you can do about that other than not using alert confirm or prompt boxes. Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Instead of using alert, create your own confirmation dialog.

Comment: @ Kevin B: i tried this if(confirm(do you realy want to delete?)) {editEleveAction.setParameter("oldName", old_name); }return false; but as i told you there was a problem  "Prevent this page from creating additional dialog boxes"

Comment: @ user1032531: how to create my own dialog?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the native alert you could use a custom dialog, there are many plugins out there.

here is a jQuery UI one http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation